# Best Way To Bring C++ Into Objective-C Project

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, cocoa

For an upcoming XCode iOS project I'm planning on writing my views and view controllers in Objective-C. My model will be provided to me in C++.

I am aware of 2 ways of using C++ in an objective-c project. They are described below. What are the pros and cons of each method. Is there any other recommended way, and what are its pros and cons?

-In C++ header files, use extern "C" declaration as described in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extern_%22C%22#Linking_C_and_C.2B.2B_code).

-Wrapping C++ with an Objective-C++ as described by [Rob Napier](http://robnapier.net/blog/wrapping-cppfinal-edition-759).

Comment: From my past experiences (using C++ libraries), all I had to do was rename my file extensions to .mm.

Comment: as theAmateurProgrammer's way:.m ==> .mm